# Not getting table prefix magento 2.1.2

Tags: magento-2.1, product-collection

I am trying to get table prefix by using the function getTableName(), But couldn't get the result, Below is my code,

```
$sum = new \Zend_Db_Expr('(SUM(`main_table`.`product_id`)/`main_table`.`product_id`)');
    $collection = $this->orderItem->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToSelect(['product_id', 'frequency' => $sum])
        ->removeFieldFromSelect('item_id');
    $select = $collection->getSelect();
    $connection = $collection->getConnection();
    $orderItemTable = $connection->getTableName('sales_order_item');

    $select->joinLeft(
        ['sub_table' => $orderItemTable],
        '`main_table`.`order_id` = `sub_table`.`order_id` AND `main_table`.`product_id` != `sub_table`.`product_id`',
        ['product_id']
    );
    $collection
        ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.product_id', ['eq' => $productId])
        ->addFieldToFilter('sub_table.product_type', ['nin' => $restrictedProductTypes])
        ->addFieldToFilter('sub_table.parent_item_id', ['null' => true])
        ->setOrder('frequency');
    $select->group('sub_table.product_id');
    $result = $connection->fetchAll($select);
```

I just tried the below code, but it forced me to set area code

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);    
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$deploymentConfig = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig');
var_dump($deploymentConfig->get('db/table_prefix'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig
 */
protected $deploymentConfig;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig $deploymentConfig
)
{
     $this->deploymentConfig = $deploymentConfig;
}
 protected function collectNewDataForProduct($productId)
{
    $orderItemTable = $this->deploymentConfig->get('db/table_prefix') . $connection->getTableName('sales_order_item');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with below method to get table prefix name,

```
protected $_resource;
public function __construct(       
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
) {
    $this->_resource = $resource;
}

public function getTable($tablename)
{
    return $this->_resource->getTableName($tablename);
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you passed $tablename as sales_order_item

Comment: yes I just tried , $this->_resource->getTableName('sales_order_item');

Comment: Have you remove var folder? Now check i have replace protected to public